# How would someone observe AVPlayerLayer's videoRect changing?

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, avplayerlayer

The Apple Documentation states that videoRect responds to KVO, although I can't figure out how to implement it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayerlayer/1385745-videorect

I have a playerLayer, but how do I add an observer for the videoRect?

```
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)

self.playerLayer?.videoRect.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:"test", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
```

My problem is that I'm trying to align an image that depends on the videoRect, but the videoRect is set to all 0's in viewDidLoad. A short moment later, it changes, so I need to observe when it changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You observe the `playerLayer`, not the `videoRect`. The `"videoRect"` is the key path.

Comment: Also I strongly recommend that you switch to Swift 4 KVO (`observe(_:options:changeHandler:)`).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work using         ```self.playerLayer?.observe(\AVPlayerLayer.videoRect, options: [.new, .old]) { object, change in
            print("VideoRect changed")
        }``` Any ideas?

Comment: Original variable looks like ```internal var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer? {
        didSet {
            self.setupRectObserver()
        }
    }```